# How do I create a nested `dict` of arrays in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array, tree, pivot-table

I need to '*pivot*' an array of arrays like this:

```py
mytable = [
    [117, 12, 'wer'],
    [117, 23, 'hgr'],
    [42, 33, 'hgj'],
    [910, 27, 'sfr'],
    [910, 31, 'mhn'],
    [910, 98, 'wlc'],
    [453, 11, 'nlj'],
    [453, 65, 'nfg'],
    [312, 17, 'fyg'],
    [312, 44, 'gfn']
]
```

into a nested dict, like this:

```py
mytree = {
    117: [[12, 'wer'], [23, 'hgr']],
    42 : [[33, 'hgj']],
    910: [[27, 'sfr'], [31, 'mhn'], [98, 'wlc']],
    453: [[11, 'nlj'], [65, 'nfg']],
    312: [[17, 'fyg'], [44, 'gfn']]
}
```

This first column is what will be pivoted and used as the `branch`, under which there will be joined - as an array of ***one or more*** arrays - all of the original arrays less the first element (which is '*promoted*' to '***parent***'). *Think Excel Pivot Table*.

**This does not work:**

```py
mytree = {}

for arr in mytable:
    toadd = {arr[0]: [[arr[1], arr[2]]}
    mytree.append(toadd)
```

I accept I may need to change the exact output structure to include more quoted key names if the example above is not accepted as valid object syntax.

Comment: Just to be precise: You don't have an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), but a `list`.

Comment: Take a look at `itertools.groupby`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method from `dict`

```
mytree = {}

for (k, *arr) in mytable:
    mytree.setdefault(k, []).append(arr)
```

Output:

```
>>> mytree
{117: [[12, 'wer'], [23, 'hgr']],
 42: [[33, 'hgj']],
 910: [[27, 'sfr'], [31, 'mhn'], [98, 'wlc']],
 453: [[11, 'nlj'], [65, 'nfg']],
 312: [[17, 'fyg'], [44, 'gfn']]}
```

Or with [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from `collections` module:

```
from collections import defaultdict

mytree = defaultdict(list)

for (k, *arr) in mytable:
    mytree[k].append(arr)
```

Output:

```
>>> mytree
defaultdict(list,
            {117: [[12, 'wer'], [23, 'hgr']],
             42: [[33, 'hgj']],
             910: [[27, 'sfr'], [31, 'mhn'], [98, 'wlc']],
             453: [[11, 'nlj'], [65, 'nfg']],
             312: [[17, 'fyg'], [44, 'gfn']]})
```